# Make a Popup window showup on clicking a html link

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, image

I need to make a popup window come up when user clicks on a html link.

Basically I'm trying to make users see a bigger picture of a wrapping paper for products.

I'm not very familiar with Javascript so any help on how to solve this step by step is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fancybox for this http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

First you need to load jQuery and fancybox to your page:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

After add link to the large image around your small image

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/large-image-name.jpg" class="various"><img src="http://www.yoursite.com/small-image-name.jpg" /><a>
```

now you need to run fancybox

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 450,
        maxHeight   : 350,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

Comment: you can use the xml to load the js files but Magento doesn't like external files (from CDN), so you have 2 options. 1- is to add this script to your cart.phtml and it will work. 2- download jquery and fancybox, load it to your js folder and add it to the site via xml. I'll go for the first option as you will load those files from CDN not your server. ---- to make the fancybox run on your link you need to add between <script> tag in your phtml file.

Comment: You can use this in your xml <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js</name></action>

Comment: Method #1 works and the popup window with the larger image is now displayed. However, popup window does not show any "close" option and I cannot return to the source page. How could I solve this?

Comment: Sorry Frank totally forgot, you need to load the fancbox images and css here is it https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/tree/master/source

Comment: Ok, thanks. Shoud I upload fancybox into magento/js folder?

Comment: if you are using method 2 yes you need to do, but you said you used method one. so all you need to do now is to load the css to your template and the images, or you can copy fancybox.css to your styles,css, don't forget in the css to change the url for fancybox images so it loads from your magneto skin folder. so background: url(fancybox_loading.gif) center center no-repeat; should be background: url(../images/fancybox_loading.gif) center center no-repeat;

Comment: Frank, if is working can you please mark the answer?