# Pop-Up Email Subscription

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, popup

I have a link in my static-block that says "subscribe". When users click that (and ONLY when they click that), I want a pop-up box to appear on the page that allows them to enter their email address to sign up to the newsletter, etc. Is this possible and what would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this extension:

- https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/magento-newsletter-popup-extension.html

If you have dev skills you can try check this tutorial:

- http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-magento-newsletter-pop-up-with-cookie/

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40056/make-a-popup-window-showup-on-clicking-a-html-link) will help you to get desired result with minor change, no need to develop an extension.

Basically you are using [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to achieve this. All you need to do is give a class name to your **subscribe** link and yes will require jquery along with fancybox js files included.

You might need to add a `newsletter` block as well to call it when clicked on **subscribe** link. If you are in static block use this code to get newsletter block:

```
<div class="your-class" style="no-display">
      {{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" as="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
</div>
```

I haven't tested, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap? That has a very nice modal, all you'd need to do is copy newsletter/subscribe.phtml to your theme then wrap the code with bootstrap modal.

In regards to your button opening and closing the modal you could use this:

```
jQuery( ".open-modal" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Where `.open-modal` is the class name for your static block element.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have enough experience with programming, I suggest to use free [Sender plugin](https://marketplace.magento.com/sendernet-synergia-sendercommerce.html) for that. This plugin have one of feature to do pop-ups in your Magneto store. After you get emails, this tools helps in others steps: manage your subscribers, send promotions, newsletters and reminders. If your store don't have many customers, you can start with free plan up to 2500 subscribers and send up to 15000 emails/month. More information about features and plans read here: https://www.sender.net/