# Custom Form in "Fancybox" Popup

Tags: magento-1.9, popup

I want to display "fancybox" popup with a custom form and a custom action in button click. I have refered the following link: [Make a Popup window showup on clicking a html link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40056/make-a-popup-window-showup-on-clicking-a-html-link).

But where can I add the custom form content to dispaly in popup?

Comment: create a custom phtml page and write your code in it and  call it from on click on button

Comment: I have tried that way. But I was not able to succeed. Could you please show the code for that.I want to display the custom form in fancybox pop up

Answer (score 0):

1) Create your module form then put the template form in a some **phtml** something like: `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/form/new-form.phtml`.

2) Put this code in the `<body>` of the fancybox `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('form/new-form.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>`

3) The fancybox you can **display** it where you want,
in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`, you add this piece of code:

```
<your_layout_handle>
   <reference name="root">
      <block type="core/template" name="fancy.block" template="path_to_your_file.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

then add this one in the file where your to display it:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('fancy.block'); ?>
```